# Command works in shell but not in subprocess

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to run a command using the python `subprocess` package. I've added the path to the compiled executable to my `PATH` on an Ubuntu machine.

When I do this, **it works**:

```
myexecutable input_file output_file
```

When I do this, **it works**:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = '/path/to/my/myexecutable input_file output_file'
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Here's the kicker.
When I do this, it **doesn't work**:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = 'myexecutable input_file output_file'
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
```

It gives me:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8f5c3da8b0a3> in <module>()
----> 1 subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))

/home/me/miniconda3/envs/mypy2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    170     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    171     """
--> 172     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    173
    174

/home/me/miniconda3/envs/mypy2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    392                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
    393                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 394                                 errread, errwrite)
    395         except Exception:
    396             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.

/home/me/miniconda3/envs/mypy2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
   1045                         raise
   1046                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
-> 1047                 raise child_exception
   1048
   1049

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What gives?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the 2 ways of using `subprocess`? Am I blind? They look the same to me...

Comment: Your works/doesn't work appear identical.

Comment: They are identical. He's trying to trick us the b*****d lol

Comment: whoops. lemme fix that

Comment: That would have been a real hard one ha

Comment: Are you including the extension on "my_executable" like "my_executable.py" or "my_executable.exe"?

Comment: You're not giving the full path in the non-working case, and the executable isn't in your `$PATH`, so it can't find it.

Comment: The two ways are **not** identical folks. One has an absolute path the other doesn't — and I suspect that's why one works and the other doesn't (because one is relative to the current working directory).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever shell you're using (as well as `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True)`, but that comes with caveats) figures out the actual executable based on the `PATH` environment variable.

`subprocess.Popen()` by itself does not. One popular way to work around this (i.e. to do that path lookup) on UNIX systems is using the widely available `/usr/bin/env` tool which does the same expansion, i.e.

```py
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'mytool', 'hurr', 'durr'])
```

but that's not portable for Windows.

The best way to go about things is to do the lookup by yourself, that is to figure out the full path of your executable file and pass it to `subprocess.Popen()` – `os.path.realpath()` might be your friend here.

Comment: Your answer is confusing.  I think all you need to say is that "myexecutable" is not in path.  Using env is not going to help him in any way.

Comment: But popen itself will not do path expansion.

Comment: Oh.  Like I said, your wording is confusing :)

Comment: @MK. Better now?